# Create a dictionary from a list of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a `list` of `list`s like the following:

```
a =  [['Product', 'Q', 'QA', 'Status'], 
      ['PS001', 500, 200, 'Good'], ['PS002', 400, 100, 'Bad']]
```

I want to create a `list` of `dict`s like the following:

```
new_list = [{'Product':'PS001', 'Q':500, 'QA':200, 'Status':'Good'},
            {'Product':'PS002', 'Q':400, 'QA':100, 'Status':'Bad'}]
```

I create a `temp_dict` with the keys of the `dict` with blank values:

```
temp_dict = {}
for i in range(len_0):
    temp_dict[a[0][i]] = ''
```

How do I append the values of `a[1:]` in the `dict` and further append them to a `list`?

I tried this:

```
new_list = []
for i in a[1:]:
    for j in i:
        for m,n in temp_dict.items():
            temp_dict[m]=j
        new_list.append(temp_dict)
```

but it gave the result as:

```
[{'Product': 'Bad', 'Q': 'Bad', 'QA': 'Bad', 'Status': 'Bad'},
 {'Product': 'Bad', 'Q': 'Bad', 'QA': 'Bad', 'Status': 'Bad'},
 {'Product': 'Bad', 'Q': 'Bad', 'QA': 'Bad', 'Status': 'Bad'},
 {'Product': 'Bad', 'Q': 'Bad', 'QA': 'Bad', 'Status': 'Bad'},
 {'Product': 'Bad', 'Q': 'Bad', 'QA': 'Bad', 'Status': 'Bad'},
 {'Product': 'Bad', 'Q': 'Bad', 'QA': 'Bad', 'Status': 'Bad'},
 {'Product': 'Bad', 'Q': 'Bad', 'QA': 'Bad', 'Status': 'Bad'},
 {'Product': 'Bad', 'Q': 'Bad', 'QA': 'Bad', 'Status': 'Bad'}]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try `zip`

```py
[dict(zip(a[0], i)) for i in a[1:]]
```

```
[{'Product': 'PS001', 'Q': 500, 'QA': 200, 'Status': 'Good'},
 {'Product': 'PS002', 'Q': 400, 'QA': 100, 'Status': 'Bad'}]
```